# Meteor facebook API : user_friends permission missing

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, meteor, meteor-accounts

I'm using account-facebook and fbgraph packages with meteor, 
my service configuration looks like this :

```
{ _id: 'zDCcCKawiBFrgLQ8Q',
   service: 'facebook',
   appId: edited,
   secret: edited,
   requestPermissions: [ 'user_friends' ] }
```

I get an access token at login and can get the email and public profile fine, but my permissions only include those permissions and not user_friends :

```
{ data: 
  [ { permission: 'email', status: 'granted' },
    { permission: 'public_profile', status: 'granted' } ] }
```

I thought user_friends was a given permission. What am I missing?

Comment: Where do you get `email` permission from, if you’re not even asking for that?

Comment: I understand that the basic permissions are provided by default? are they not? EDIT : I think they come from the access token that I get from the login. I tried to remove the requestPermissions from the service config and it seems to have no impact.

Comment: They are _approved_ by default, meaning you do not have to get them reviewed by Facebook, before you can ask normal users for them. But it does of course _not_ mean that users will automatically _grant_ those permissions to your app – you still have to _ask_ for them.

Comment: I understand that but accounts-facebook already asks for those and gives back an access token? That's where email and public_profile are coming from I think.

Comment: Ok the Meteor.loginWithFacebook was not setup properly, it wasn't asking for any permissions. By requesting the proper permissions I got what I wanted. The weird thing is that I got permissions without asking for them in the first place... :-/

Comment: That might have been permissions you granted to your app at an earlier point in time, or in a different way (f.e. testing in Graph API Explorer, …)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED by rewriting the loginWithFacebook:

```
Template.third_party.events({
  "click .btn-facebook": function(e, t){
    Meteor.loginWithFacebook({
      requestPermissions: ['email', 'user_friends']
      }, function (err) {
      if (err)
        Session.set('errorMessage', err.reason || 'Unknown error');
    });
  }
});
```

Where third party is the template that includes the facebook button.

Comment: Can you please post how? I'm having the same trouble.

Comment: Also make sure your facebook app is properly configured

Comment: Thanks for being super prompt! `{ permission: 'user_friends', status: 'granted' }`

Answer (score 1):

A better solution would be to include the following configuration in your client-side code:

```
Accounts.ui.config({
    requestPermissions: {
        facebook: ['user_friends']
    }
});
```